# Broken image when printing rdlc report

Tags: asp.net, cross-browser, rdlc

I have an rdlc report that in visual studio looks ok (see red rectangle in image below), but when i print it in an asp.net application a kind of "broken link" image appears.
This was not appening before i started modifying this asp.net application.

Which could be the cause?

[image: Visual Studio on the left, asp.net app on the right]

**UPDATE**: I found the problem is only when using Chrome, from IE it is fine.

Comment: <style type="text/css">body:nth-of-type(1) img[src*="Blank.gif"]{display:none;}</style> add this css to your page it will be solved.

Answer (score -2):

here is the solution for your problem

http://dyslexicanaboko.blogspot.in/2012/11/ssrs-report-viewer-control-broken-image.html